# Mysql query for grouping orders with specific data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two mysql tables:

```
    1. orders 
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | address |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | aaa  | asd asd |
| 2  | bbb  | sdf sdf |
| 3  | ccc  | dfg dfg |
+----+------+---------+
    2. order_intra 
+----+----------+----------+-------+
| id | order_id | quantity | price |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
| 1  | 1        | 4        | 10    |
| 2  | 1        | 1        | 11    |
| 3  | 3        | 10       | 5     |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
```

The first table is the list of orders, and the second one is the list of ordered products quantity and prices (order_id in the second table is id from the first table)

I want to build the resulting table:

```
    3. result 
+----+------+---------+----------+
| id | name | address | ordersum |
+----+------+---------+----------+
| 1  | aaa  | asd asd | 51       |
| 2  | bbb  | sdf sdf |          |
| 3  | ccc  | dfg dfg | 50       |
+----+------+---------+----------+
```

**ordersum** is sum of all quantity*price for order with same order_id as in table 1.
But some orders are "empty":  we have them in orders table,  but no any products for them in order_intra table.

I run this:

```
SELECT orders.*, SUM(order_intra.quantity*order_intra.price) AS ordersum 
FROM orders, order_intra WHERE order_intra.order_id=orders.id 
GROUP by orders.id
```

and get this:

```
+----+------+---------+----------+
| id | name | address | ordersum |
+----+------+---------+----------+
| 1  | aaa  | asd asd | 51       |
| 3  | ccc  | dfg dfg | 50       |
+----+------+---------+----------+
```

order number 2 is lost!   **How to change my query so that it's return includes  "empty" orders?**
Here is MCVE:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f0d488/2/0

EDIT: I finished with this:

```
SELECT orders.*, sums.ordersum FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_id, SUM(order_intra.quantity*order_intra.price) AS ordersum      
FROM order_intra GROUP BY order_id) AS sums ON orders.id=sums.order_id 
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  Put all non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY clause.  Replace * with column names.  Start a good habit when writing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so (`LEFT JOIN ... ON`):

```
select orders.*,
       sum(orders_intra.quantity*orders_intra.price) as ordersum
  from orders left join orders_intra on orders_intra.order_id=orders.id
  group by orders.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works.  However I am concerned about using joins because really the tables have much more fields and a lot or rows,   hopefully it will not slow the things down.

Comment: The join operation is the only way to combine fields from different tables using relations.  Your example query is also using a join even if it does not explicitly use the word `JOIN`.

Comment: ha, it doesnt work on real database:   #2006 - MySQL server has gone away,   however if I test it at sqlfiddle - it works. oh   12000 and 15000 rows in tables,  it cant be true